# How can display recycler view using fragment in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display recycler view inside fragment but i am getting **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference.** . Code is given below .

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);


        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        ArrayList<String> values = getArguments().getStringArrayList("arrayList");

        RecyclerViewAdapter cl = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ctx, values);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cl);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Change `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);` to return `rootView ;`

Comment: @Piyush thank you , now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a view (in the first line) and you are ignoring it and returning something else.

You should do this :

```java
return(rootview)
```

Comment: why i am getting negative vote for this question ?? and also i am not able to ask any question in stack overflow. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

I think your context is not passed in constructing linearlayoutmanager